# How to Sync Realm Data to Amazon Dynamo Db (Cloud)

Tags: android, python-3.x, react-native, realm, amazon-dynamodb

I am using Amazon Dynamo DB as my main database and [Realm](https://realm.io/) as the local (offline) DB. My data is stored in Realm DB and I am trying to sync the data in Realm up into to Amazon Dynamo DB.

I tried with Realm to MySQL and MongoDB but I did not find what I need(Synchronize data to another database)

```py
realm = new Realm({
    path: 'UserDatabase.realm'
});
this.state = {
    input_user_id: '',
    userData: '',
};
```

This is not the actual code. I've been trying for two weeks to sync Realm to Dynamo.

I'm looking for a solution to save data from React Native to Realm and then to sync it up to Amazon Dynamo DB.